# 'Blob is not defined' error in async-array-buffer. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side-rendering

I'm getting error when trying start SSR and import { AudioContext } from [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context/)

```
/workspace/node_modules/async-array-buffer/build/es5/bundle.js:10
    var blob = new Blob([worker], {
               ^

ReferenceError: Blob is not defined
    at /workspace/node_modules/async-array-buffer/build/es5/bundle.js:10:13
    at /workspace/node_modules/async-array-buffer/build/es5/bundle.js:2:65
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/async-array-buffer/build/es5/bundle.js:5:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Module._compile (/workspace/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/workspace/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How to possible to fix and where i need start to dig?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Blob in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637644/how-do-i-create-a-blob-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, install the below package

-> npm install blob-polyfill

After that go to server.ts file, make an import and add blob to global.

-> import { Blob } from 'blob-polyfill'

-> global['Blob'] = Blob

I guess now you are all set to go.