# How to make csv file from editor

Tags: javascript, csv

Now I have tried to make csv file from Visual Studio Code.
I found a code to make csv file from editor.
However, the code is not working.
Please give me advise to resolve a problem in the code.

*Win 10 pro 64 bit, VScode: 1.45.1, node.js: 13.14.0, clasp: 2.3.0

```
let blob = new Blob(['ABC'],{type:"text/csv"});
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'made from vscode.csv';
link.click();
```

I modified first sentence. text/plan to text/csv

Comment: What do you mean by **not working**? Can you please explain e.g. did you get any error message? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, this is not correct: `let blob = new Blob(['ABC'],{type:"text/plan"});`. It should be `text/csv`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have a error in debug console. The error is ReferenceError: Blob is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for additional comment. I modified the code but same error is continued. Please give me more advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to reproducible. It works fine for me...

Comment: Check the answer of this post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637644/how-do-i-create-a-blob-in-node-js

I guess you are mixing up client side with server side javascript... this is why it doesn't work. You are doing it server side and probably some of you are testing it clientside.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understood the root cause my issue. I should do clientside, right? How do I select it ?

Comment: I found first sentence in debug console of VSCode is written regarding to the node.js. C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node.exe ..\test.js  How do I change I want to do the code clientside.

Comment: Please give me a hint how to get out of clasp's environment.

Comment: Error message is below.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node.exe" --inspect-brk=16158 '"..\make csv file\test.js"'
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:16158/da2f118f-a0f8-460a-b905-b997384180d2
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
ReferenceError: Blob is not defined

Comment: at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\name\make csv file\test.js:1:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1115:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47